# What recent way is there in achieving a floating action button in xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-native

please can anyone help me in achieving a floating action button in xamarin.ios? All I see over the internet is xamarin forms. I'm getting this has been answered but the solution I found has been deprecated since 2018, I need this for my final project guys any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with **Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponents** package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.iOS.MaterialComponents#readme-body-tab